# What to do while designing an SQL Server Db to support German and Turkish

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am about to design and develop a web application that may need to support multiple languages such as English, German and Turkish. I will be using ASP.NET (Webforms) 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 Standard. Inserts, updates and selects will be inline statements. There will be exports (from GridView to Excel) and file uploads (using either varbinary max or FileStream). I will also be having charset set to utf-8 as a meta tag at the html side.

Is it enough to choose nvarchar as data type (for the fields that may store German and Turkish) and use N before the string values inside the inline statements? Is there any other items that I need to be careful about?

Comment: I am not familiar of sql server but in `mysql` i use character set `utf8mb4unicode` for multilanguage web pages and it is enough for me. From mysql dev center `Consequently, if you want to upgrade tables from utf8 to utf8mb4 to take advantage of supplementary-character support.`